# Really simple Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, vbscript

Sorry, I am terrible at regular expressions, but I am trying to find one that will match any string that ends with the string ".wim" with nothing else after it. For example, given the following strings:

```
Vista32Sp2_SL-56-GB3.wim
Vista64Sp2_SL-56-GB3.wim
Win864_SL-IN-869.wim.old0613
```

I want my regular expression to match the first 2, but not the last. The string must END in .wim, not just contain it. My first attempt at the Regex was `^.*\.wim$` but I put that into a Regex Tester online and it didn't work.

Comment: `^.*\.wim$` should work (although `\.wim$` should as well).

Comment: this works in rubular: http://rubular.com/r/JBL3J0R9xQ

Comment: why not just `\.wim$`?

Comment: I tried it here http://www.myregextester.com/index.php and it didn't work

Comment: I know why it didn't work: You entered all three strings into the regex tester textbox together, right? Well, then it can't match because a) the dot doesn't match newlines, and b) your string doesn't end in `.wim`. `^` and `$` mean "start/end of *string*", not "start/end of *line*" unless you use the `/m` modifier.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Now any idea why it would not be working in VBS?

Comment: Case in point: http://regex101.com/r/bN8uJ7 - your regex works, you just need to learn how to use your regex tester.

Comment: Well, how are you using it in VBScript? Should we guess?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I got it working now actually! Thank you very much

Comment: @TimPietzcker "\.wim$" doesn't seem to work even when I enable the "m" flag on that site... shouldn't it?

Comment: @ctn - depends if you have carriage returns embedded along with the new lines. In windows, a new line is actually `\r\n`, but `$` will only match the position up to the `\n`, in which case your expression would need to be `\.wim\r?$`

Comment: @Tim - so we have ctn putting comments in the answers and you putting answers in the comments. This question is completely knackered. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you tried works:

```
^.*\.wim$
```

I tried this on www.regextester.com and it works. By default, on that site, the matching text is replaced with what you enter in "Replace with" and you only remain with "Win864_SL-IN-869.wim.old0613" which is ok.

You could try [regexpal](http://regexpal.com). I often find it more useful.

Depending on the regex engine ".*" can match greedily (including the ".wim") so by the time it tries to match ".wim" it's already past it. In such a case Jerry's answer is more appropriate (with PCRE compatible expressions, I believe)

Comment: This is what the OP said was tried. So, this is really a comment

Comment: hmmmm that is weird. I tried it on http://www.myregextester.com/index.php and it didn't work

Comment: myregextester doesn't seem to recognize the $ character. This character is quite basic and, as far as I know, should be recognized by all regex engines.

Comment: hmm ok I figured it out tho now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to capture the contents of the matching string, just check whether it matches or not, then `^.*?` is unnecessary; all you need is:

```
\.wim$
```

Comment: +1 - it's the *only* correct answer (so far), because by keeping it *simple* it avoids all the problems that spring up when you add further funny letters to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
^.*?\.wim$
```

`.*?` is nongreedy so it won't match `.wim`

Comment: I am doing the regex in VB script and its not working. Could the RegEx pattern syntax be different for VBS?

Comment: That regex always matches *exactly* the same text as the OP's regex (because of the anchors). The explanation you just added is wrong (or at least beside the point), too.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Both should work. And there's nothing wrong in the explanation.

Comment: Yes, the owner's problem is different (see my comment to the question).

Comment: This is incorrect. `.*?` is indeed non-greedy, but `.*` is not an atomic expression, meaning it will give up characters in order to satisfy a match. With the anchors in place, both expressions will match exactly the same (though via different routes).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(?<=\s|^)\S+\.wim(?=\s|$)
```

(if your goal is to use this with php, ruby, don't work for javascript or VBscript)

For VBscript use this, the result is in the capturing group:

```
(?:\s|^)(\S+\.wim)(?:\s|$)
```

or

```
(?:\s|^)(\S+\.wim)(?=\s|$)
```